# How set same height in group of listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have some problem with generating listbox.  
I have dataset with many rows and i need to split one big table to two or more depends on some RowsLimit. One table with 100 rows will became two tables with 50 rows and so on. These blocks will display next to each other.  
For this I use listbox with grouping (in code behind I set property for filtering) and it works well. But each row has different height and I need last row in group fills all remaining space in every group. 
I tried use dock panel, but it changes nothing.

Also I need create and set GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate in runtime, because I have in my dataset number of columns, width, bordercolor, and other properties. How can I replace DataTemplate "HeaderGroupStyle" with new?

```
<ListBox Name="lbTable" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderGroupStyle">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="Header 1" />
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="Header 2" />
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="Header 3" />
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="Header 4" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Cell[0].Value}" />
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Cell[1].Value}" />
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Cell[2].Value}" />
                <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Cell[3].Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderGroupStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle> 
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>
```

This is what I have now
[image]
And this is what I want
[image]

Comment: Im just gonna place that here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_9
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340710(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I thougth about grid, yes. It would bo so easy solution. But does it split itself depends on some count of row?

Comment: @Mishka, i need to copy header many times and set user's margin between new table blocks. DataGrid always displays rows in one table. Or not? Do you have some example or links? But, thanks for helping ))

Comment: I believe you are talking about the Style of the DataGrid/Row/ColumnHeader/Cell, which you can edit to set margins etc'.
For example you can search online, there are many example to view:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples